# multiple fonts in pyqt5?

Tags: python, user-interface, fonts, pyqt5

I made a Gui in qt designer and I was wondering if I could add multiple fonts so that it works on multiple Operating systems.

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
<span style="font-family: arial, helvetica ,sans-serif">
   <font size="1">
       [Country]
   </font>
</span>
```

The fonts i want are Consolas, Menlo, DejaVu Sans Mono, monospace

Heres the python code for my gui so far:

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1000, 1000)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QSize(1000, 1000))
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(31, 36, 33);")
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.welcomeMessage = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.welcomeMessage.setObjectName(u"welcomeMessage")
        self.welcomeMessage.setGeometry(QRect(30, 160, 951, 41))
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.welcomeMessage.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.welcomeMessage.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.welcomeMessage.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.welcomeMessage.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        self.welcomeMessage.setLayoutDirection(Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.welcomeMessage.setStyleSheet(u"font: 30pt \"Consolas\"; color: rgb(240, 240, 240);")
        self.welcomeMessage.setTextFormat(Qt.AutoText)
        self.welcomeMessage.setScaledContents(False)
        self.welcomeMessage.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.welcomeMessage.setWordWrap(False)
        self.welcomeMessage.setMargin(0)
        self.welcomeMessage.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QRect(160, 620, 681, 141))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(u"color: rgb(31, 36, 33); font: 20pt \"Consolas\"; background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240); \n"
"selection-color: rgb(41, 47, 43);\n"
"")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 1000, 26))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Password Generator", None))
#if QT_CONFIG(whatsthis)
        self.welcomeMessage.setWhatsThis("")
#endif // QT_CONFIG(whatsthis)
        self.welcomeMessage.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Welcome to the Password Generator!", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Click here to generate a password!", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

I havent tried using multiple fonts on it yet.

Comment: Overriding the system fonts is generally a terrible idea from the UI perspective, and usually completely unnecessary: a program is not a web page, its most important aspect is usability, and almost always the font change causes more unforseen problems than benefits (which usually is just the attempt of the programmer to "make it look good" just to *their* own eyes and taste). Most importantly, there are users that have specifically chosen custom fonts due to their visual impairment, and you shall *always* consider that before overriding anything. In any case, to what do you want to set fonts?

Comment: If it's application-wide, use [`QApplication.setFont()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#setFont), otherwise you should set an application [stylesheet](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html) (**always** using proper [*selectors*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types)) to target specific classes or objects, but be aware that using too many fonts in a program is usually extremely distracting (and almost always useless and annoying to the user). Obviously, the fonts must be installed, otherwise you must use QFontDatabase.

Comment: Finally, unrelated but extremely important: 1. *always* use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) (fixed geometries are discouraged and almost always used for the *wrong* reasons and in the *wrong* way); 2. Maybe you already know that, but better safe than sorry: never, *ever*, manually edit files generated with pyuic; **always** follow what explained in the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).